# Add - Remove and Reset fields Dynamically

Tags: angular

I am making a dynamic form for Add,Remove and Reset the fields, on Add and Remove my functionality is working fine but on click of Reset it is resetting the whole form instead of reset that particular group of inputs.

here is my workings:
**App.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="FormGroup">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
          <div style="margin-top:0px" formGroupName="itemRows">
              <div class="row panel-heading text-bold" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 10px;">
                  Dynamic Row Add - Form Details
              </div>
              <ng-container *ngIf='FormGroup.controls.itemRows!=null'>
                <div class="" *ngFor="let itemRow of FormGroup.controls.itemRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]='i'>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                        <input type="text"  placeholder="Name" formControlName="Name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                          <input type="text"  placeholder="Roll No." formControlName="RollNo">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                          <input type="text"  placeholder="Class" formControlName="Class">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                          <input type="text"  placeholder="Mobile No" formControlName="MobileNo">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                          <button type="button" (click)="addRows()" [disabled]="FormGroup.invalid" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right:10px;">+</button>
                          <button (click)="deletRow(i)" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right:10px;">x</button>
                          <button (click)="resetField()" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
              </ng-container>
              <!--<button type="button" (click)="addRows()" [disabled]="FormGroup.invalid" class="btn btn-danger">Add Rows</button>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ɵConsole } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, NgForm, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { formsignup } from './formsignup';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'angular8Projects';

    FormGroup:FormGroup;
    TotalRow:number;

constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit():void {
this.FormGroup = this._fb.group({
  itemRows: this._fb.array([this.InitItemRow()]),
})
}

InitItemRow(){
return this._fb.group({
  Name:[''],
  RollNo:[''],
  Class:[''],
  MobileNo:['']
})

}

resetField(){
  const control =<FormArray>this.FormGroup.controls['itemRows'];
  this.FormGroup.reset()
}

addRows(){
  const control = <FormArray>this.FormGroup.controls['itemRows'];
  control.push(this.InitItemRow())
}

deletRow(index: number){
  const control = <FormArray>this.FormGroup.controls['itemRows'];
  if (control != null){
    this.TotalRow = control.value.length;
  }
  if (this.TotalRow > 1 ){
    control.removeAt(index);
  }else {
    alert ('one recorder is mandatory');
    return false;
  }
}
}
```

your early reply appreciated.

Comment: You are resetting `itemRows` so it is resetting ALL rows, maybe try to reset the `itemRow` and send it via `(click)="resetField(itemRow)"` -- It is just not so clear what you try to do.

Answer (score 1):

To make @TheNsn666's comment explicit:

In your template you want:

```
(click)="resetField(itemRow)"
```

in your ts code:

```
resetField(group: FormGroup){
  group.reset()
}
```

---

As an aside I recommend using a getter to simplify your both your template and ts code:

```
get itemRowsArray {
    return this.FormGroup.controls.itemRows as FormArray
}
```